# how can i remove entire row if a column has more than 10 characters using pandas

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Delete entire record if column is more than 10 characters how can i delete that entire record.

My dataframe is

```
Sl.no     name                 reason
1         sara                 hello 
2          ram                  how are you?
3          raghu                how do you do?
4          sai                   hey !!
```

**Expected Output**:

```
Sl.no     name                 reason
1         sara                 hello 
2          sai                 hey !!
```

Thanks inadvance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with inverted mask from `>` to `<=` and find lengths by [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
df = df[df['reason'].str.len() <= 10]
print (df)
   Sl.no  name  reason
0      1  sara   hello
3      4   sai  hey !!
```

Answer (score 1):

Boolean indexing with a list comprehension is efficient:

```
df = df[[len(i) <= 10 for i in df['reason']]]
```

But there are a few other approaches:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*2000)

%timeit df['reason'].map(len).le(10)          # 2.32 ms per loop
%timeit df['reason'].str.len().le(10)         # 2.6 ms per loop
%timeit [len(i) <= 10 for i in df['reason']]  # 1.18 ms per loop
```